# Heatbeat 2.13 for solaris 10

Tags: solaris, heartbeat

I am setting up a High availability cluster server using heartbeat in solaris 10. I have compiled and add the package successfully after couple of hours tried.

However i do not find any documentation online for solaris 10 configuration in two nodes. Only for Linux system(since heartbeat is linux openware)

Have anybody ever configure in solaris 10 and make it work?

Thanks in advace if any helpful tips

Answer (score 0):

A more usual configuration is two cluster nodes and a quorum server.  I have never had to develop heartbeat software like you describe in order to get a Solaris cluster going.  Solaris has its own version, and it is usually meant for a geo cluster.  geo cluster == geographically spread out cluster

This explains using heartbeat for a geo cluster:

```
http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1416/6nmdd2phk?l=en&a=view
```